# If A = a list, and I let B = A, will changing of B change A?

Tags: python

I was trying to solve a problem and I encountered this situation:

```
A = ['2', '3', '4', '1']
B = []
for item in A:
    B += [item]
for i in range(len(A)):
    B[int(A[i]) - 1] = str(i + 1)
    print(int(A[i]) - 1)
```

The output reads

```
1
2
3
0
```

This is fine. However, in my first attempt, I actually did

```
A = ['2', '3', '4', '1']
B = A
for i in range(len(A)):
    B[int(A[i]) - 1] = str(i + 1)
    print(int(A[i]) - 1)
```

But this time the output reads

```
1
0
3
2
```

I don't see the reason the two outputs being different. I thought in both codes B are similarly defined- which is equal to A at first.

Comment: if you do `B = A`, `A` and `B` both point to the same list object. If you change `A` you change `B` aswell. You can use `B = A.copy()` instead

Comment: @luigigi so ```A = B``` means ```B = A```?

Comment: After the assignment `A = B`, `A is B` and `B is A`. Both variables have a reference to the same value.

Comment: This is actually surprising for me. I thought after ```B = A```, the assignment ends, the line runs only once, so changing B will not change A because I do not run ``` B = A ``` again nor ``` A = B ```. Say if I let A = a list, B undefined, and run ```A = B```, I will then get undefined error, although A and B are 'tied together' after ```A = B```.

Comment: And sorry I am rather new here why do I get my text but not codes highlighted in my comment above although I have enclosed the codes with ```